# The inverse function of Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArray or `fixed`?

Tags: arrays, .net, marshalling

`Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement` lets me take a byte array, and turn it into a pointer.

`fixed` keyword does something similar, and gives me a pointer but it also offers a guarantee that the array won't be moved by GC.

But what is the reverse API which lets me turn a pointer like this into a managed byte array that I can pass to stream APIs etc? Is it possible to do without copying the data?

Comment: No, you can't turn an arbitrary pointer into a managed array without copying.  It is unlikely you have to when you can use UnmanagedMemoryStream.  Some day I'll figure out why I an experienced SO user forces me to guess at this, that day is not yet close.

Comment: @Hans Passant I did not know about UnmanagedMemoryStream, so thanks for sharing that. That might be one of those 'even better than the answer you thought you were looking for' answers.